What’s going on with my esp32? Getting a weird text when minicom
I tried to minicom into my esp32 but am getting the following looping error .. any ideas what could have happened? Doesn't look like a typical core dump that I've seen.


It’s the bootloader output. The watchdog triggered a reset. Something is NQR with the code you loaded.

NQR? What do you mean by this?

Not quite right.
